# Django ChainedForeignKey smart menu

Tags: python, django, select, menu, many-to-many

i am trying to make a chained select menu, i have this model:

```
from django.db import models

class Health_plan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Doctors_list(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    health_plans = models.ManyToManyField(Health_plan, related_name="doctors")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And this is my `forms.py`:

```
class SpecForm(ModelForm):
    a = Doctors_list.objects.values_list('specialty', flat=True)
    unique = [('---------------','---------------')] + [(i,i) for i in set(a)]
    specialty = forms.ChoiceField(choices=unique)
    class Meta:
        model = Doctors_list

class HealthForm(ModelForm):
    hplan = ChainedForeignKey(
        Health_plan, 
        chained_field="specialty",
        chained_model_field="specialty", 
        show_all=False, 
        auto_choose=True
    )
```

my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from testApp.views import spec_form
from testApp.views import health_form 
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'Medbook.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^Medbook/', include('Medbook.foo.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^hello/$',  spec_form, health_form),
)
```

and my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response 
from testApp.forms import SpecForm
from testApp.forms import HealthForm

def spec_form (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SpecForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = SpecForm()
    return render_to_response('hello.html', {'form':form})

def health_form (request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HealthForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = SpecForm()
    return render_to_response('hello.html', {'form':form})
```

By now the error i get is `'function' object is not iterable` when i acess the webpage.
I am new to Django and i find this tricky. The user must select one specialty, and then should appear the health_plans that cover that specialty.

The health_plans have a manytomany relationship with the doctors. When a person chooses a specialty, the script should check wich doctors belong to that specialty and retrieve all the health plans hold by those doctors.

I hope i made it clear, for my code it isn't.

Any help kindly appreciated

EDIT: Stack Trace

`Internal Server Error: /hello/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 103, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 321, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 221, in resolve
    kwargs.update(self.default_args)
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
[08/May/2013 19:30:45] "GET /hello/ HTTP/1.1" 500 62490`

Comment: can you show the urls.py ?

Comment: updated, see above, added views.py too

Comment: what is `url(r'^hello/$',  SpecForm, HealthForm)` ?

Comment: sorry, i copied a outdated version of urls.py, already updated

Comment: should `url(r'^hello/$',  spec_form, health_form)` not be `url(r'^hello/$', spec_form)` ? the url format is `url(pattern,  viewname, name, kwargs)`

Comment: u're right, i can acess the web page now, but my chained menu just presents: `Health_plan object` , any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

`url(r'^hello/$', spec_form, health_form)` to `url(r'^hello/$', spec_form)`

Also, In the models:

```
class Health_plan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s"%(self.name)
```